# How to instal my asus xtion pro live on unbuntu 12.04?

Tags: ros, asus-xtion-pro-live

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to install my asus xtion pro live on Ubuntu 12.04 hydro, but when I have plug my sensor, he is "detected" but there are no name.
What is the procedure to install correctly this sensor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162961/how-to-instal-my-asus-xtion-pro-live-on-unbuntu-12.04?/) by [guigui](https://answers.ros.org/users/16871/guigui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could install using

$sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-camera

$sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [guigui](https://answers.ros.org/users/16871/guigui/) on 2014-05-08**:
after trying your command and i try lsusb and I receive this. what the next step?

guillaume@guillaume-VirtualBox:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1d27:0601
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

thanks for your help